# Mysql спасет ли партицирование от нехватки ram

Tags: mysql, innodb

есть сервер mysql 5.6   с таблицами innodb, есть таблица с полнотекстовым индексом и обемом 1гб. После того как таблица перевалила за 1гб, поиск резко замедлился так как размер innodb_pool  как раз 1гб. И видимо таблица не влезает полностью и начинается работа с диском.
Поможет ли разбиение таблицы на партиции? Например разбить по критерию года создания?

Comment: Переносите эту задачу на инструменты, предназначенные для полнотекстового поиска

Comment: Это усложнит решение и плюс, у этой таблицы слишком живой контент.....много обновлений...